# Parsing horizontally aligned text file to DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing

I am working with data in txt file which are aligned horizontally, and I would like to align it into columns for example in a DataFrame.

Capitalized code on the beginning of each line (ID, AC etc) should be column names. There are more codes then in the provided example, and when an object does not have information for a particular code it should be empty.

Each object is separated by `//`.
List of all codes:`['ID', 'AC', 'AS', 'SY', 'DR', 'RX', 'WW', 'CC', 'ST', 'DI', 'OX', 'HI', 'OI', 'SX', 'AG', 'CA', 'DT']`

The problem is that some codes occur several times, like CC or OX. I tried to put it into dataframe and transpose it but to be honest I am stuck with how to match the columns to appropriate elements in the text file and what to do when an entity does not have information for a particular code.

```
ID   #16-15
AC   CVCL_KA96
DR   RCB; RCB4635
DR   Wikidata; Q54422067
RX   PubMed=25400923;
CC   Monoclonal antibody isotype: IgM.
CC   Monoclonal antibody target: UniProtKB; Q5T5X7; Human BEND3.
OX   NCBI_TaxID=10090; ! Mus musculus
OX   NCBI_TaxID=10116; ! Rattus norvegicus
HI   CVCL_4032 ! P3X63Ag8.653
CA   Hybridoma
DT   Created: 22-08-17; Last updated: 07-09-18; Version: 2
//
```

And I would like the data to be organized in columns for example:
[image]

Comment: Please, do not  include images of code. Instead, use the "code block" feature when editing to include the actual code. This leverages the work needed to create a solution.

In case you haven't already, as a new user, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

I've done this without `pandas`, but the output, based on the file sample from the question, resembles the one you expect.

```
import csv
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

with open("sample.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines = [l.strip().split('   ') for l in lines if l != '//']

data = defaultdict(list)

for line in lines:
    key, values, = line
    data[key].append(''.join([v for v in values.split(";")]))

with open("test.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(data.keys())
    writer.writerows(itertools.zip_longest(*data.values()))
```

Output:

[image]

EDIT: with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd


codes = [
    'ID', 'AC', 'AS', 'SY', 'DR', 'RX', 'WW', 'CC', 'ST', 'DI', 'OX', 'HI',
    'OI', 'SX', 'AG', 'CA', 'DT',
]


with open("sample.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines = [l.strip().split('   ') for l in lines if l != '//']
print(lines)

data = {c: [] for c in codes}

for line in lines:
    key, values, = line
    data[key].append(''.join([v for v in values.split(";")]))


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').transpose()
df.to_csv("test_2.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a good start, however I still do not know how to handle situation when a particular object does contain data on particular code i.e. it is empty. On the excel sheet that I attached above you can see for example code AS, SY that contain no data. That means I need to add define the column names beforehand right? I also got an error complaining on the loop in both solutions. 

´key, values, = line ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)´
I guess its complaining on the ['//']

Comment: Can you update the sample with one that contains empty values for a given code?

Comment: Items are listed with only those codes that they have values for. That means that if a particular object does not have a value for a specific code - it will just skip that code instead of having null or empty field.

Comment: I fixed the error btw. The '//' has new line after it so it works for mw with '//\n'